# vue @touchleave

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Пытаюсь сделать адаптивное меню на VUE JS. Получается нормально обрабатывать события mouseenter,
mouseleave, touchstart. Но не ловится событие touchleave (прикосновение за пределами элемента). Хочу, чтобы прикосновение за пределами элемента скрывало элемент. Как это правильно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Вешайте событие на документ и делайте проверку

```
document.addEventListener('click', evt => {
  if (!evt.target.closest('.class')) {
    this.showMenu = false
  }
})
```